# how to transpose the table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

How to convert columns and primary rows??

tbl1

```
     |   p1   |   p2   |   p3   | ...
g1   |    1   |   2    |    3   | ...
g2   |    4   |   5    |    6   | ...
g3   |    7   |   8    |    9   | ...
```

expected result

```
     |   g1   |   g2   |   g3   | ...
p1   |    1   |   4    |    7   | ...
p2   |    2   |   5    |    8   | ...
p3   |    3   |   6    |    9   | ...
```

how to make expected result table with tbl1

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is 'pivot table'. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: How many columns `pX` do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept of PIVOT table in MySql.

Here I have given solution of your problem considering columns P1,P2 and P3.See this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5d64/1) and understand how it works after that you will be able to do it by your own.

```
SELECT TEMP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'G1' THEN value END) `G1`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'G2' THEN value END) `G2`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'G3' THEN value END) `G3`
  FROM
(
  SELECT unit, TEMP,
         CASE TEMP
            WHEN 'P1' THEN P1
            WHEN 'P2' THEN P2
            WHEN 'P3' THEN P3
         END value
    FROM tbl1 t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'P1' TEMP UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P3' 
  ) c
) q
 GROUP BY TEMP
 ORDER BY FIELD(TEMP, 'P1', 'P2', 'P3')
```